# running deja-dup as cronjob, BU disc not connected

Tags: cron, deja-dup

I have a problem with my backup cronjob. I use these settings (as proposed in [that post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54644/how-can-i-set-up-hourly-deja-dup-backups/67011#67011)):

> 15 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/deja-dup --backup

During runtime deja-dup says:

```
Backup location not available. Waiting for 'xy' to become connected...
```

The external disk 'xy' is mounted; I can also create a backup when I run deja-dup --backup in the command line.

Any ideas what the problem could be? Could it be a permission issue? But crontab runs the job with my user I suppose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with deja-dup not working reliably when executed via cron. The (very unsatisfying) answer is, that it's simply not designed to work from cron.

- [Explanation](https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/HowItWorks#Why_Not_Cron.3F)
- [Feature request to enable time scheduled backups](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191)

One possible solution is to use duplicity for doing cron scheduled backups. Duplicity is the backend deja-dup connects to.

Comment: that page doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Page is now https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Details#Why_Not_Cron.3F

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a workaround for this. First, you need to have installed dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then run it and open org/gnome/deja-dup/file. There, change the "type" from "volume" to "normal"

[image]

Alternatively you could just execute this command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/deja-dup/file/type "'normal'"
```

Some notes, though:

- Tested in Ubuntu 16.04
- I have not tested what happen if the volume is not actually mounted
- I have not tested either what happen if you change your Deja Dup settings later, but I think it will probably reset that value, so you'll have to edit it by hand again (or add the previously mentioned command to your crontab before the dejadup --backup one)

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around is to use "local" backend instead of "volume". Only thing you need is a static backup path, in my case it's `/media/filip/red/backup`.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/deja-dup/backend "'local'"
dconf write /org/gnome/deja-dup/local/folder "'/media/filip/red/backup'"
```

The volume (here `/media/filip/red`) is LUKS-encrypted volume mounted from USB stick. But on my Ubuntu (20.04) deja-dup does not detect this LUKS drive when running from cron, for some reason.